# Shimmer animation not stopping on load of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have a Recycler View that gets its data from firebase and what i want to do is that when all the data is loaded and once the recycler view is populated then the shimmer animation should stop and go away. I have tried the same with progressbar and it worked without any hiccups. But incase of shimmer animation its not stopping. I have created 2 methods one to start the animation and other other one to stop the animation. Please help me with my code and suggest what i need to change in order to achieve the desired result. I am calling the stopLoading function inside my onBindViewHolder. Thanks in advance.

```
public class buynow extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference ProductRef;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
private String searchText = "";

public void showLoading(){
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view);
    shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmerAnimation();
}

public void stopLoading(){
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view);
    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buynow);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(buynow.this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        searchText = extras.getString("phone_name");
    }

    setActionBarTitle();

    showLoading();

    Toast.makeText(buynow.this,"Loading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText){

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = ProductRef.orderByChild("pname").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
            .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,Products.class).build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder>(options) {


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Products model) {

            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getPname(), model.getPprice(), model.getPmrp(), model.getPcondition(), model.getPimage());
            stopLoading();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.buy_now_phones,parent,false);
            return new UsersViewHolder(view);

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

//View Holder Class
public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    private UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    private void setDetails(Context context, String phoneName, String phonePrice, String phoneMrp, String phoneCondition, String phoneImage){

        TextView phone_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        TextView phone_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        TextView phone_mrp = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_mrp);
        TextView phone_condition = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_condition);
        ImageView phone_image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);

        phone_name.setText(phoneName);

        //fromatting phone price
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(phonePrice);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        phone_price.setText("₹"+formatter.format(amount));

        //fromatting phone mrp
        double amount0 = Double.parseDouble(phoneMrp);
        DecimalFormat formatter0 = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        phone_mrp.setText("MRP "+formatter.format(amount0));
        phone_mrp.setPaintFlags(phone_mrp.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        phone_condition.setText(phoneCondition);
        Picasso.with(context).load(phoneImage).into(phone_image);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(buynow.this,buynow_device_search.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void setActionBarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Used Phones");
}

}
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".buynow">

<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shimmer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/place_holder_layout"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/place_holder_layout"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/place_holder_layout"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/place_holder_layout"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/place_holder_layout"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/place_holder_layout"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first declare [**`ShimmerFrameLayout`**](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/) globally.

```
private ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerLayout;
```

Then declare onCreate() section

```
 shimmerLayout      =findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view);
```

For Show case,

```
  shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  shimmerLayout.startShimmer();
```

For Stop case,

```
 if(shimmerLayout.isShimmerVisible())
       {
           shimmerLayout.stopShimmer();
           shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
```

### CODE EDIT

Try with

```
public class buynow extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference ProductRef;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
private String searchText = "";
ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buynow);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(buynow.this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        searchText = extras.getString("phone_name");
    }

    setActionBarTitle();

    ProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    shimmerFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view);
    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    Toast.makeText(buynow.this,"Loading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText){

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = ProductRef.orderByChild("pname").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
            .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,Products.class).build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder>(options) {


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Products model) {

            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getPname(), model.getPprice(), model.getPmrp(), model.getPcondition(), model.getPimage());

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.buy_now_phones,parent,false);
            return new UsersViewHolder(view);

        }
    };

    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

//View Holder Class
public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    private UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    private void setDetails(Context context, String phoneName, String phonePrice, String phoneMrp, String phoneCondition, String phoneImage){

        TextView phone_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        TextView phone_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        TextView phone_mrp = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_mrp);
        TextView phone_condition = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_condition);
        ImageView phone_image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);

        phone_name.setText(phoneName);

        //fromatting phone price
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(phonePrice);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        phone_price.setText("₹"+formatter.format(amount));

        //fromatting phone mrp
        double amount0 = Double.parseDouble(phoneMrp);
        DecimalFormat formatter0 = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        phone_mrp.setText("MRP "+formatter.format(amount0));
        phone_mrp.setPaintFlags(phone_mrp.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        phone_condition.setText(phoneCondition);
        Picasso.with(context).load(phoneImage).into(phone_image);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(buynow.this,buynow_device_search.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void setActionBarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Used Phones");
}

}
```

Comment: isShimmerVisible() not wokring

Comment: use   `implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'`

Comment: Not working it still keeps displaying the shimmer animation and not stopping it. i am calling it inside onBindViewHolder

Comment: @careaboutdevelopment stop function should be after `recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);`

Comment: @careaboutdevelopment Solved this yet?

Comment: No, Now it's just executing the stop at the start and not showing any shimmer animation at all.

Comment: added the xml file

Comment: @careaboutdevelopment Check edited answer. I am sure it will work

Comment: I have copied tried with your code and now its displaying nothing just blank white screen.

Comment: there are no errors or anything. Maybe it is something to do with compatibility.

Comment: i would've but it didn't fixed the issue

Comment: @careaboutdevelopment `Maybe it is something to do with compatibility` share please

Comment: The Code Edit you have posted is displaying a blank screen.

Comment: I have given the right check..You are right maybe it is compatibility. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as in the OP's code a call to method `startShimmerAnimation()` is there which means OP is using the dependency

`com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar`

so its better to change to

`com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0`.

Now the problem is **ShimmerFrameLayout** have an attribute `app:shimmer_auto_start` which is set to `true` by default and because of which **ShimmerFrameLayout**'s shimmer starts automatically and can't be controlled by methods `startShimmer()` and `stopShimmer()`.

So if you want to control starting and stopping of the shimmer of the **ShimmerFrameLayout** then you have to set the `app:shimmer_auto_start` attribute of the **ShimmerFrameLayout** to `false` explicitly in the **XML Layout** file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can explain exactly why it's not working onBindViewHolder. I think this is about onBindViewHolder. But I know why we saw white screen in the previous edited code ( shared by IntelliJ Amiya ). There is no time between starting and ending of shimmer and therefore it starts and ends quickly. But if we set the time, we can see it starts and ends. We just need Handler. And after stopping we should use

> shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

instead of

> shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

that shimmerFrameLayout doesn't take up space.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }, 1000);
```

Even if there is no internet, Firebase RecyclerView shows the information obtained when it was the last internet connection. If we delete any data on Firebase while the application is closed and then open the application, it will show the data we opened the application for the last time and after a few time update it. We can give it time to update through the Handler and let it update the data before the data appears. So I think it makes sense to use Handler. After editing full code:

```
 public class buynow extends AppCompatActivity {

 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
 private DatabaseReference ProductRef;
 private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
 private String searchText = "";
 ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_buynow);
 Firebase.setAndroidContext(buynow.this);

 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 if(extras != null){
    searchText = extras.getString("phone_name");
 }

setActionBarTitle();

ProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

shimmerFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view);
shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


Toast.makeText(buynow.this,"Loading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText){

Query firebaseSearchQuery = ProductRef.orderByChild("pname").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
        .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,Products.class).build();

firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder>(options) {


    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Products model) {

        holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getPname(), model.getPprice(), model.getPmrp(), model.getPcondition(), model.getPimage());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.buy_now_phones,parent,false);
        return new UsersViewHolder(view);

    }
};

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}, 1000);

recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}
```